# Retrofit GET parameters error

Tags: android, retrofit2

Although, i have no exception on the console, passing parameters to the GET request with @PATH disfigure the URL and generate a 404 response.

```
  @GET("user/authentif/{login}/{pwd}")
  Call<User> login(@Path("login") String login,@Path("pwd") String pwd);
```

and this is the call

```
    apiService = RestService.createService(SolarAPIService.class);
    Call<User> call=apiService.login(email,pass);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            mEmailView.setText(Integer.toString(response.code()));
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: what is error?
please post User class for full code solution.
btw you will get User object in response.body();
not response.code();

Comment: Check your url .You may have enter incorrect url.Also donot send your password like that using GET ,it is insecure.

Comment: are you sure that your email and pass not null?

Comment: I'll check the email and password but the URL itsel work just fine when I don't send any parameters

Comment: @JaydeepPatel its a 404 not found

Comment: yes it turns out the email and pass are coming null

Comment: Retrofit doesn’t allow you to pass null as a value for path parameters. That mean server inability to response your request. I think problem is your url, It might be incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that instead of getText I was using getEditableText so mya parameters were null and caused the 404 not found error